Solve the integral and use Taylor series
My teacher gave me the following exercise:
The integral $\int \sqrt{1+x^3} dx$ cannot be found with the integral table.
a) Construct an initial value problem which has the function
$$f(x)= -\int_0^x \sqrt{1+t^3}  dt \tag{1}$$
as a solution in the segment $[0,5]$.
b) Use the Taylor series method of order $3$, with $h=1/64$, to find the values ​​of function $(1)$ in the segment $[0,5]$.
I am mainly having problems with the integral I tried just replacing the $dt$ with $d(1+t^3)$ but I ended up with $$\frac{2 {(1+x^3)}^{3/2}} {9 x^2}$$
Which doesn't work because you can't divide by zero and any other solution of the integral I found online were too complicated.

Why not $y'=\sqrt{1-x^3}$? And apply Taylor method?

You need to solve the integral for point a) anyway and you only apply the Taylor method for point b) plus I don’t think my professor would accept it if it was that easy

I don't think they'd ask that because this integral involves the hypergeometric function. In any case you could expand $\sqrt{1+x^3}$ around $x=0$.

My professor actually made a problem for everyone in our class where he only changed the equation,the h,the segment and the order of the Taylor equation so I did consider that he might have given me this equation without realising it’s difficult by accident but unfortunately he is on break for two weeks and I need to turn this in on Monday

You do not need to evaluate the integral to solve this problem. You're asked to approximate $f(x)$, not find it exactly. See Wikipedia's graphic accompanying the entry for Euler's method; you're essentially constructing the red segmented curve for the approximation to $f(x)$, not the blue curve corresponding to the exact solution $f(x)$.

Choose a convenient initial value $x=x_0$ that makes determining $f(x_0)$ easy. Since you're approximating $f(x)$ on $[0,5]$, $x_0=0$ is the obvious choice.
Use the fundamental theorem of calculus to recover a differential equation. You're already given $f(x)$, so you need only differentiate to get an ODE of the form
$$f' = g(x, f(x))$$
Now apply Taylor's method. With the starting point $(x_0,f(x_0))$, let $x_1=x_0+h$ and approximate $f(x_1)$ with the Taylor expansion
$$f(x_1) \approx f(x_0) + h f'(x_0) + \frac{h^2}2 f''(x_0) + \frac{h^3}6 f'''(x_0)$$
Repeat to approximate $f(x_2)$ where $x_2=x_1+h$,
$$f(x_2) \approx f(x_1) + h f'(x_1) + \frac{h^2}2 f''(x_1) + \frac{h^3}6 f'''(x_1),$$
and so on, calculating $f(x_i)$ using $f(x_{i-1})$ and the respective derivatives at $x_{i-1}$, up until you reach $f(x_i=5)$.
In other words, fill out the table below with enough sample points such that $x_N=5$.
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
i & x_i & f(x_i) \\
\hline
0 & x_0 & f(x_0)=? \\
1 & x_1=x_0+h & f(x_1)\approx? \\
2 & x_2=x_0+2h & f(x_2)\approx? \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
N & x_N=x_0+Nh & f(x_N)\approx?
\end{array}$$
Given the step size $h=\dfrac1{64}$, you're looking at $320$ iterations. It's probably doable by hand within a week but I'm not about to test that hypothesis.
